# enforce vs. force

Tags: vocabulary

Is there any difference in meaning between "to enforce" and "to force" when used in the below context?

> The earthquake enforced changes in construction regulation.

> The earthquake forced changes in construction regulation.

Are both uses ok?

Thank you.

Comment: Those words have different meanings. Have you looked the up in a dictionary? On this site, we require people asking questions to show they've tried to answer the question themselves with online resources before asking here.

Comment: Yes, I have looked up in various dictionaries. Some definitions seem to overlap. For instance, one of the definitions of "to enforce" is "to force".

Comment: Can you add that information to the question.  "I have looked in XYZ dictionary and the definition of enforce is ...."

Answer (score 1):

To "enforce" is to use force to cause something to happen.  It implies an agent that has a purpose.  So you can say that the "police enforce the law".  The police have an aim, and they use force to achieve that aim.

But an earthquake doesn't have a purpose. So it is very odd to say "the earthquake enforced..."

Answer (score 0):

One of the definitions of *enforce* is *cause (something) to happen by necessity or force*, so I think you *can* use it here.

You *force* someone to do something, you don't force the action - so if you use it you would have to say

> The earthquake forced the authorities to make changes in construction regulation.